# About Laravel time function

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2,
my question is about Laravel time function.

For example:
Now is `2016-04-21 03:01:20`,
I would want to record the last second in 30 days, that is `2016-05-21 23:59:59`,
How to do it?

Comment: You could easily make use of [Carbon Dates] (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to manipulate date objects in Laravel and PHP in general.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need?

```
Carbon::now()->addDays(30)->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```